# Matplotlib Axes3D Ratio Savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a little problem with matplotlib.
The size assignment is good when displaying (plt.show()) a 2D or 3D visualization.
But does not happen if it's a 3D visualization during the save (Fig.savefig(...))
The easiest way is to show the result.
Have you an Idea ?

**FILES** : 
[2DVisualisationFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0649a.png)
[3DVisualisationFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJCgt.png)

**PYTHON SCRIPT**

```
# coding: utf8
import os
import numpy as np

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # noqa: F401 unused import
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DPI = 150
FIG_SIZE = (8.60, 5.40)

mu = 1
sigma = 0.75

S = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size=(1000,3))

# 2D Visualisation
Fig = plt.figure(figsize = FIG_SIZE, dpi = DPI)
ax = Fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(S[:,0], S[:,1], alpha=0.5)
print(Fig.get_size_inches())
plt.show()
Fig.savefig(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/Samples_Test.png", transparent = False, bbox_inches = 'tight', dpi=DPI)
plt.close('all')

# 3D Visualisation
Fig = plt.figure(figsize = FIG_SIZE, dpi = DPI)
ax = Fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(S[:,0], S[:,1], S[:,2], alpha=0.5)
print(Fig.get_size_inches())
plt.show()
Fig.savefig(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/Samples_Test2.png", transparent = False, bbox_inches = 'tight', dpi=DPI)
plt.close('all')
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Which version of matplotlib are you using? How are you running the code?

Comment: The last version it's new install with py3. I run the script with vs code runner or powershell

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that with `bbox_inches = 'tight'` the figure size can be changed during saving, see [matplotlib.pyplot.savefig](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html).

Instead use `bbox_inches = None` and the saved figure will have the correct size.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

FIG_SIZE = (6, 3)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = FIG_SIZE)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot([0,1], [0,1], [0,1])
plt.show()

fig.savefig("bbox_inches_tight.png", bbox_inches = 'tight')
fig.savefig("bbox_inches_None.png", bbox_inches = None)
plt.close('all')
```